# How essential is Incorruptible to Irredeemable?

Tags: comics, irredeemable, boom-studios

Please don't post spoilers, I'm at Volume 7 of Irredeemable and have the first two volumes of Incorruptible.

**How essential is Incorruptible to the main storyline of Irredeemable?**

I know that there is a crossover in Irredeemable Vol 9, is it essential that I am up to date with Incorruptible before reading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a crossover, as Max Damage's origin story collides with that of the Plutonian, but Max's presence in the *Irredeemable* storyline is short and you can skip reading *Incorruptible*.

IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, so if I read Irredeemable Vol 9 without reading the rest of Incorruptible I wouldn't miss out on anything?

Comment: I believe so. I was all stoked to see how the crossover would go, and then wondered why they bothered.